# export const getting undefined

Tags: react-native, export

When I am accessing const value of a js file from my another js file am getting undefined Data

**Abc.js**

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

      const abc = Platform.select({
        ios: [
          'com.abc',
          'com.xyz'
        ],
        android: [
          'com.pqr',
          'com.lmn'
        ]
      });

    export default abc
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import { abc } from "./Abc";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});


onPressgetData = () => {
  console.warn("DATA " + JSON.stringify(abc));
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          !! Welcome to React Native !!
        </Text>
        <Button title="get Data"
          color="#841584"
          onPress={() => onPressgetData()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

I am accessing abc const data from my App.js when I click get Data instead of array I am getting undefined in warning. I don't know where I have mistaken Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are exporting a single component from a file you can use `export default abc` and this can be imported directly in other files by `import abc from './abc'`

When your files have many components/functions, you will have to export each function individually using `export functionName` and import them using

`import { functionName, functionName2, functionName3 } from './abc'`

You can also use `export default SpecialFunctionName` along with other exports.
So, when you

`import SpecialFunctionName(can use any name here) from './abc'`

you will always get `SpecialFunctionName` as it was `default export`-ed.

Answer (score 8):

You've exported your module as `default` and importing it as a `named import`, therefore it is undefined.

Change

```
import { abc } from "./Abc";
```

to

```
import abc from "./Abc";
```

to get correct result